# TextBox Set Cursor at end after KeyUp or KeyDown

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, cursor, keydown

I have a list with previous entries of my *TextBox*. By using *KeyUp* / *KeyDown* I can scroll through this list showing the text in the TextBox.

Setting another string in the *TextBox* the edit-cursor should be at the end of the string in the Te*emphasized text*xtBox. *myTextBox.Select(RTextBox.Text.Length, 0);* is very useful here but after *KeyUp* this is setting the cursor not at the end of the text, it's one character before. After *KeyDown* its at the end, correct. I guess according to the naming **preview** the current character is not yet calculated in, but even adding +1 to the length doesn't work.

```
 private void MyTextBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.KeyValue)
        {
            case (char)Keys.Up:
                myTextBox.Text = GetNewText();
                myTextBox.Select(myTextBox.Text.Length, 0);
                break;

            case (char)Keys.Down:                  
                myTextBox.Text = GetNewText();
                myTextBox.Select(myTextBox.Text.Length, 0);
                break;
        }
    }

 private void MyTextBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.KeyChar)
            {
                case (char)Keys.Up:
                   // I'd guess setting the cursor here would be perfect
                   // but KeyUp/KeyDown can't be caught here, unfortunately
                   myTextBox.Select(RTextBox.Text.Length, 0);
                   break;
            }
         }
```

So I think that I have to set the cursore after the *PreviewKeyDown*-Event but in case of *KeyUp* / *KeyDown* I don't know if this is possible at all.

Any other event where I should set the cursor?

Edit: I'm using WinForms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add this line if it's a `Keys.Up` or a `Keys.Down` and use the `KeyDown` event:

```
e.Handled = true;
```

It means, that the normal behavior is skipped. At the end you have this:

```
private void MyTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.KeyValue)
    {
        case (char)Keys.Up:
            e.Handled = true;
            myTextBox.Text = GetNewText();
            myTextBox.Select(myTextBox.Text.Length, 0);
            break;

        case (char)Keys.Down:                  
            e.Handled = true;
            myTextBox.Text = GetNewText();
            myTextBox.Select(myTextBox.Text.Length, 0);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: _PreviewKeyDownEventArgs_ has no possibility for _e.Handled_

Comment: Oh sorry I thought you're using WPF. Are you using Windows Forms?

Comment: I updated my answer: Then you have to use the `KeyDown` event.

Comment: Thank You! I should have known it, when the new character is not yet calculated in inside the preview-event there must be a another event. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help, if this answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer. see: [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more information